# Using Graphite with Golang

Tags: go, graphite

I am trying trying to write test data to graphite and expecting a graph but it is now showing up as a graph. It is a simple program.

Program basically writes 50k numbers in a single Metrics. As I have used SimpleSend as per which it would write Key, Value and timestamp by itself.

I see dummy.data namespace created and I was expecting a graph.

Pease let me know what is the issue

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    graphite "github.com/marpaia/graphite-golang"
)

func init() {

    host := "172.31.5.221"

    port := 5050

    var err error

    Graphite, err = graphite.NewGraphite(host, port)

    fmt.Println(err)

}

var Graphite *graphite.Graphite

func main() {

    for value := 1; value < 50000; value++ {

        err := Graphite.SimpleSend("dummy.data", fmt.Sprintf("%v", value))

        if err != nil {

            fmt.Println(err)
        }   

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing was wrong

Graphite was configured to 1 minute and thus this was resulting in within 1 ms execution. Only a point was created